# Scipy, Pandas find maximum peak within subset of peaks

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Have a bit of a complicated scenario, hopefully the solution is easy!

I want to find the highest peak within a set time-frame of an acceleration.

An acceleration is defined as over 140. The acceleration starts when it crosses 140 and stops when it falls below 140.

Then what I want to do is find the highest peak within that acceleration, i.e. if there are 5 peaks within one acceleration only tag the highest one.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Find the accel peaks that are over 140
# The peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(df['value'])

# new column with peak tags
df.at[[index for index in peaks], 'accel_peaks'] = 'peak'

# Only keep those which are above 140
df['accel_peaks'] = np.where(df['value'] >= 140, df['accel_peaks'], np.nan)
```

I'm hoping there is a variable in find_peaks, or peak_prominences I can use.

Would appreciate any help / guidance thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the minimum peak height directly in `find_peaks` (see [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html))

```py
peaks, _ = find_peaks(df['value'], height=140)
```

Then, to find the highest peak, simply sort the peaks index returned by the peak value and take the first one, something like (haven't tested):

```py
peaks.sort(lambda x: df['value'][x])
```